# Partitions stop to mount after update

Tags: partitioning, mount

I applied updates on 29.01.2019 and shutdown notebook. It was yesterday.
Today (30.01.2019) I started system and figured out that some partitions were not mounted.
When I try to mount then I receive error:

> Error mounting system-managed device /dev/sda2: mount(2) system call
>   failed: Structure needs cleaning

I checked partition but no errors were found.

Moreover I tried to boot previous configuration (4.15.0-43-generic) and all works fine - all partitions are mounted properly.
It seems that something changed with last update which prevents partitions to be mounted.
The problem with 4.15.0-44-generic configuration.

How I can figure out the cause and fix it?
Or may be I need to provide more detailed information?

Thank you!

Comment: Is /dev/sda2 a Windows/NTFS partition? Are there other partitions not mounting?

Comment: No it is Ext3 partition. I have two physical disks - primary SSD with Ubuntu and secondary SATA with two partitions - both are Ext3. And both partitions on the SATA disk are not mounted with the same error.

Comment: Do you know how to fsck the two ext3 partitions? It sounds like the problem is on /dev/sda2, and wouldn't that be on your SSD? Let me put together a quick answer that might help. Please remember to accept my answer if it was helpful. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks to all.The problem was solved with the next Ubuntu base update.

Answer (score 0):

**Note: I'm assuming that /dev/sda2 is your Ubuntu system partition...**

To check the file system on your Ubuntu partition...

- boot to the GRUB menu
- choose Advanced Options
- choose Recovery mode
- choose Root access
- at the # prompt, type `sudo fsck -f /dev/sda2`
- repeat the `fsck` command if there were errors
- type `reboot`

If for some reason you can't do the above...

- boot to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB
- open a `terminal` window
- <strike>type `sudo fdisk -l`</strike>
- identify the /dev/XXXX device name for your "Linux Filesystem"
- type `sudo fsck -f /dev/sda2` # <strike>replacing XXXX with the number you found earlier</strike>
- repeat the fsck command if there were errors
- type `reboot`